# Trying to toggle cases with ASCII values

Tags: java

Ok,I'm just an amateur in programming,so go easy on me. So, I'm coding the classic toggle cases program but without using the .toUpperCase() or the .toLowerCase() functions but instead using ASCII values of the characters. I manage to convert the upper cases to lower but cant seem to do the opposite.

package toggle;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Toggle {
    String str;
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    public void toggleStr()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        str=sc.nextLine();
        char c;
        int res;
        char ch[]=str.toCharArray();

        for(int i=0;i<ch.length;i++)
        {
            res=(int)(ch[i]);
            if((res>=65)||(res<=90))
            {
                c=(char)(res+32);
                System.out.print(c);
            }
            else if((res>=97)||(res<=122))
            {
                c=(char)(res-32);
                System.out.print(c);
            }

            else
                System.out.print(ch[i]);
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Toggle t=new Toggle();
        t.toggleStr();
    }
}
```

Comment: `if ((res>=65)||(res<=90))` So if res == 1 this is true? Don't think that's what you want.

Comment: This would look better if you used char literals instead of int literals (e.g., 'A' instead of 65 and so on).

Comment: Also, FWIW, we're not in ASCII anymore:  Java is strictly Unicode.  The values of the Unicode code points for 'A'-'Z' and 'a'-'z' happen to have the same numeric values as in the old ASCII encoding, but what happens when you want to convert 'å' to uppercase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`||` should be `&&`, in both cases. Any number is greater than 65 or less than 90, so the first `if` block gets executed each time, regardless of the character.

Comment: Yep,TY. as I said amateur.

Answer (score 2):

All values from 97 to 122 are greater than 65, so your first `if` condition will include the lower case as well as the upper case characters. You need to use `&&` instead of `||` (and instead of or).

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about good old ASCII table then each small letter differ from big letter by only one bit (2^5, 6th bit) represented by decimal 32 or hex 0x20.

But if we are talking about XXI century unicode we can use the java std library functions.

Below I show both versions:

**ASCII style:**

```
public String toggleAscii(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' || c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            boolean isLower = (c & 0x20) == 0x20; // binary 100000 (sixth bit, 2^5)
            c = (char) (isLower ? (c & 0xdf) : (c | 0x20));
        }
        sb.append(c);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

**Unicode style:**

```
public String toggle(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        boolean isUpper = Character.isUpperCase(c);
        sb.append(isUpper ? Character.toLowerCase(c) : Character.toUpperCase(c));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```